# is there a way to crop a given 3d image using coordinates in java?

Tags: java, arrays, cropimage.net

my function is: `public static int[][][] crop(int[][][] img, int i_1, int j_1, int i_2, int j_2)`
as the pixels are (i_1,j_1),(i_2,j_2) and the function should return a new 3d array cropped from (i_1,j_1) to (i_2,j_2) and the size of the new image should be ) (i_2-i_1+1)*(j_2-j_1+1)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have a photo which i want to crop by two given pixel coordinates which is from (i_1,j_1) to (i_2,j_2) and the new size of the image should be (i_2-i_1+1)*(j_2-j_1+1)

Answer (score 1):

**I guess this is what you are looking for:**

```
    public static int[][][] crop(int[][][] img, int i_1, int j_1, int i_2, int j_2) {
    int[][][] newImage = new int[3][i_2 - i_1 + 1][j_2 - j_1 + 1];

    for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (i_2 - i_1 + 1); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < (j_2 - j_1 + 1); j++) {
                newImage[k][i][j] = img[k][i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return newImage;
}
```

First line of code takes and returns a three dimensional array (may it be a picture with color format RGB) as its first parameter. The other parameters are coordinates of the cropping matrices.

Inside the block of code a shallow copy of the original picture is declared for variable *newImage*, so that a cropped portion of the original picture will be returned later.

The main part of the block of code are the nested loops:

1. *k* runs on RGB array which is the first array with indexes 0,1,2;
2. *i* runs on the coordinates of the rows of the array inspected (hence this is your vertical indice);
3. *j* runs on the coordinates of the columns of the rows of the array inspected(hence this is your horizontal indice).

The statement inside the nested loop appends the original pictures pixel (located in the range of the coordinates) to the returned cropped array named *newImage*.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: if you can explain a little bit i would be happy @mabadai